# subscriptcorrection in newtxmath + listings + subscript in literate = 

Tags: listings, subscripts, newtxmath

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}% subscriptcorrection not really needed for this minimal example but is helpful in general
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible,mathescape=true,literate={{₁}{$_1$}1}]
  f$_1$ // ok
  f₁ // error with subscriptcorrection
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.9   f₁
           // error with subscriptcorrection
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Of course, `f$_1$` instead of `f₁` works, so a workaround on the document level is available.  Is there a better solution on the preamble level or even package level?  The intention is to type `f₁` into your source LaTeX document and get `f₁` in the resulting PDF document.

Comment: use `literate={{₁}{$\sb1$}1}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks!!! I completely forgot that `\sb` and other commands for subscripts exist as well. I presume that `literate={{₁}{\textsubscript{1}}1}` would do equally well, wouldn't it?

Comment: `\textsuperscript` uses text fonts, `_{}` or `\sb{..}` uses math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my more realistic sources I both upright function names and upright indices have to be typeset, e.g., `div₁`, `div₂`, `f₂`, and `div₃`. Any idea whether textual `\textsubscript{…}` is any better or worse than `$\sb{…}$` in this context?  The results looks the same to me and to diffpdf so far.

Comment: @GeekestGeek looks like math to me. It may be you are using the same font for text and math digits, but they are logically distinct and specified separately.